# how to find the most relation drug and disease given doctor orders

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

```
I have the following data:
```

| Drugs | Diseases |
| --- | --- |
| drug1,drug2,drug3 | dis1,dis3 |
| drug1,drug4 | dis1,dis2 |
| drug1,drug2,drug4,drug7 | dis1, dis3,dis4,dis7 |
| drug1,drug3 | dis1,dis3 |

- describe：first column is drugs the patient take; the second column is
  the disease given by doctor;
- need：I want to find the
  (diseaseX,drugY) pairs, which indicate that for diseaseX, the drugY
  is used for it.
  for the given example, should output (dis1,drug1), because the two always exist simultaneously. but how to find all the pairs for much more data in the similar format?

Comment: What if one drug can treat more than one disease? Or one disease can be treated by multiple drugs?

Comment: @Mark or if one drug counteracts the effect of another one ;). I can imagine the methods in the scientific article "drug efficiency was inferred using code from a random person on stackoverflow".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no effort shown, it is just a code requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: You can't seriously conclude on the efficiency of a drug or whether a single drug is prescribed for a single disease with simple counts of co-occurrence.

That said, if you simply want to have an idea of the counts, you can `split` the strings, `explode` them successively, then `value_counts`:

```
(df.assign(Drugs=df['Drugs'].str.split(','),
           Diseases=df['Diseases'].str.split(','))
   .explode('Drugs').explode('Diseases')
 .value_counts()
 )
```

Output:

```
Drugs  Diseases
drug1  dis1        4
       dis3        3
drug2  dis3        2
drug4  dis1        2
drug3  dis1        2
       dis3        2
drug2  dis1        2
       dis4        1
       dis7        1
drug1  dis7        1
       dis2        1
       dis4        1
drug4  dis2        1
       dis3        1
       dis4        1
       dis7        1
drug7  dis1        1
       dis3        1
       dis4        1
       dis7        1
dtype: int64
```

If you want the most frequent combination, add `.idxmax()`:

```
('drug1', 'dis1')
```

Comment: I agree your opinion，It is not appropriate to say that the drug is used for the disease according their co-occurrence, some drugs is commonly used for many diseases. The difficult of this problem is how to filter out these common drugs. Now I filter the common drugs only by the diversity of disease co-occurrenced with the specific drug

Comment: So, does the code work for you?